# Example of sets with different specifications

Tags: real-analysis

(a) A set S with sup S = 2 = max S, inf S = 1, but minS does not exist.

(b) A set T which is bounded above, but not bounded, and which has no maximum.

(c) A set U with only rational elements, with min U = −1 and supU = ∞.

Below are the answers that I have,

a) (1, 2], the open interval on the left side signals that minS does not exist or it is infinite.

b) (x ∈ R : x < 3) or (-∞, 3)

c) {r ∈ Q : r ≥ -1}

I just want to make sure that I'm on the right path.

Comment: Every answer is correct.

Comment: Thank you for checking my answers

Comment: You're welcome. The next time, I suggest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).